# Using espresso, webClick() a dropdown list in webview?

Tags: android-testing, android-espresso

Our app is kind of a hybrid app. In the webview part of the app, I am trying to find and click the dropdown list.

The element is found and clicked but the click does not really happen. I do not see any errors, which means the click is happening just in the wrong place. I have tried various different combinations of css selectors. They all pass but it doesnt seem to be clicking in the right place.

Anyone know if there are issues with webClick() for dropdown lists?

```
public void clickNextOnDomainScreen() throws InterruptedException {
        onWebView()
                .withElement(findElement(Locator.CSS_SELECTOR, "fieldset > form#userStoreForm.form-userStore > div.clearfix > div.login-field > select#userStoreDomain.login-select"))
                .perform(webClick());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
onWebView(Matchers.allOf(isDisplayed(), isJavascriptEnabled()))
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "//option[@value='01']"))
            .perform(webClick());
```

it's work fine for me

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term value.
Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what
limitations and assumptions apply.